# After rEFInd install, on reboot boot manager does not show, boots to macOS utilities

Tags: mac, macos, utilities, efi

after installing rEFInd boot manager on my macbook pro '15 w/ macOS sierra, on boot my computer takes ~20-30 seconds on a black screen then boots directly to macOS utilities. I don't know why this is happening, I am unable to boot into my regular OS. The only way I can do this is by pressing x and directly booting from the recovery screen

Second edit: It seems that when I hold space and spam enter, it will boot me into macos. Perhaps the ui is broken for refind?